# Start activity from service and get result from activity

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity

How I can get response from Activity, which start from my Service?

I start my Activity in Service's code:

```
      Intent intent = new Intent( context, ActivityMy.class);
      intent.putExtra( "iii",    iii);
      context.startActivity( intent);
```

startActivityForResult available from Activity but no Service.

How I can get response from Activity?

Update: I need not only send one value from Activity to Service, I need run immediately my code when Activity is finished and return result.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Class that extends of Application and set it in Manifest (just set the `android:name` attribute in `<application>`). In this class you can put a static variable called activity and set everytime you change the activity. So in your Service you will can access the activity by using `MyApp.activity`

Comment: I need not only send one value from Activity to Service, I need run immediately my code when Activity is finished and return result.

Comment: I didn't get it. Don't you want start an activity from service's code?

Comment: I need get response from activity in service when activity finished.

Comment: In this case you will need a Handler. So, when the activity is finished you send the response by the handler variable and deal with it in service. Did you get it?

Create a class that extends of Handler and then you call `sendMessage`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use `BroadcastReceiver` to send broadcast from Activity to Service.

Comment: I can't send broadcast from Activity, because Activity not in main code, it in attached own library. And from Activity (inside library) not visible any attributes of Service (parent main code).

Comment: If you cannot change Activity code, your service can get nothing from your Activity when it is finished.

Comment: I think you should have read Google's [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) about startActivity